# How do Make my win and loss counter on my dice roll game output the correct numbers using visual basic

Tags: vb.net

I created the craps dice game as you press play your dice rolls if you roll the winning number or losing number when you first hit play it will tell you. if you dont win or lose on first roll you have the chance to use the roll button in order to keep rolling until you win or lose against the first set of dice rolled

i tried using an if else statement to determine the win count and display to the label although it only displays wins if you win on the first roll as you hit the play button not if you win and it took you multiple rolls clicking the roll button

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class CrapsGame
    ' die roll constants
    Enum DiceNames
        SNAKE_EYES = 2
        TREY = 3
        CRAPS = 7
        LUCKY_SEVEN = 7
        YO_LEVEL = 11
        BOX_CARS = 12
    End Enum

    ' file name and directory constants
    Const FILE_PREFIX As String = "/images/die"
    Const FILE_SUFFEX As String = ".png"

    ' instance variables
    Dim myPoint As Integer = 0
    Dim randomobject As New Random()
    Dim winCount As Integer
    Dim lossCount As Integer

    ' begin new game and determine point
    Private Sub PlayButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PlayButton.Click

        'intialize variables for new game
        myPoint = 0
        PointBox.Text = "Point"
        OutputLabel.Text = " "

        ' remove point die images
        PointDie1PictureBox.Image = Nothing
        PointDie2PictureBox.Image = Nothing

        Dim Sum As Integer = RollDice() ' roll dice

        'check die roll
        Select Case Sum
            ' win on first roll
            Case DiceNames.LUCKY_SEVEN, DiceNames.YO_LEVEL
                OutputLabel.Text = "you win!!"

                ' lose on first roll
            Case DiceNames.SNAKE_EYES, DiceNames.TREY, DiceNames.BOX_CARS

                OutputLabel.Text = "sorry you lose."
            Case Else ' player must match point
                myPoint = Sum
                PointBox.Text = "Point is " & Sum
                OutputLabel.Text = "Roll again!"
                PointDie1PictureBox.Image = Die1PictureBox.Image
                PointDie2PictureBox.Image = Die2PictureBox.Image
                PlayButton.Enabled = False ' disable Play Button 
                RollButton.Enabled = True ' enable Roll Button

        End Select ' sum
        If (Sum = myPoint Or Sum = DiceNames.CRAPS) Then
            If OutputLabel.Text = "you win!!" Then
                winCount = winCount + 1

            Else
                lossCount = lossCount + 1

            End If

            Label1.Text = "Win Count - " & winCount.ToString() + Environment.NewLine + "Loss Count - " & lossCount.ToString() + Environment.NewLine
        End If

    End Sub ' playbutton click

    ' determine outcome of next roll 
    Private Sub rollButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RollButton.Click

        Dim sum As Integer = RollDice() ' roll dice 

        ' determine outcome of roll 

        If sum = myPoint Then ' player matches point 
            OutputLabel.Text = "You win!!!"
            RollButton.Enabled = False ' disable Roll Button 
            PlayButton.Enabled = True ' enable Play Button 

        ElseIf sum = DiceNames.CRAPS Then ' player loses 
            OutputLabel.Text = "Sorry, you lose."
            RollButton.Enabled = False ' disable Roll Button
            PlayButton.Enabled = True ' enable Play Button 

        End If

    End Sub ' rollButton_Click

    ' generate random die rolls 
    Function RollDice() As Integer

        ' roll the dice 
        Dim die1 As Integer = randomobject.Next(1, 7)
        Dim die2 As Integer = randomobject.Next(1, 7)

        ' display image corresponding to each die 
        DisplayDie(Die1PictureBox, die1)
        DisplayDie(Die2PictureBox, die2)

        Return (die1 + die2) ' return sum of dice values 

    End Function ' RollDice 

    ' display die image 
    Sub DisplayDie(ByVal die As PictureBox, ByVal face As Integer)
        ' assign die images to PictureBox 
        die.Image = Image.FromFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory & FILE_PREFIX & face & FILE_SUFFEX)

    End Sub ' DisplayDie 


End Class
```

Comment: You need to debug your code properly, by setting a breakpoint and stepping through the code. You need to determine at each step whether the code did what you expected it to do. If it doesn't then you have found the issue and, if you still can't work it out for yourself, you can explain to us EXACTLY where and how the code behaviour differs from your expectation. If it behaves as you expect but still doesn't produce the correct result then it's your expectations that need fixing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment your counters (winCount or lossCount)  in the rollButton_Click subroutine. Currently the counters are only being updates when the Play button is clicked.